# Как скопировать данные из одной таблицы в другую в python (Sqlalchemy)?

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

Есть две модели Product и TempProduct

```
class TempProduct(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'temp_products'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Unicode(255), nullable=False, unique=True)
    price = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    data = Column(DateTime)
    id_product = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('products.id'))

class Product(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'products'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Unicode(255), nullable=False, unique=True)
    price = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    data = Column(DateTime)

    product = relationship("TempProduct", backref="products", uselist=False)
```

Как скопировать данные из Product в  TempProduct???